# Foreign key SQL syntax

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, multiple-columns

Let's suppose that there are two tables `table1` and `table2` where the second one references the first one.

I was wondering whether the following two forms of defining their foreign key relationship results in the same table structure of the second table.

```
CREATE TABLE table1(a INT, b INT, PRIMARY KEY(a, b));
```

1)

```
CREATE TABLE table2(a INT, b INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(a, b) REFERENCES table1(a, b)
);
```

2)

```
CREATE TABLE table2(a INT, b INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(a) REFERENCES table1(a),
    FOREIGN KEY(b) REFERENCES table1(b)
);
```

I would presume that there is no difference but couldn't find any reference to support this claim.

Comment: Why don't you try to run your code? The 1st create should fail (more than one PK). And there's a huge difference between #2 and #3, #2 is a multi-column FK, while #3 are two single-column FKs.

Comment: They are vastly different. The first one defines the foreign keys seperately and the second one defines a foreign key that references that **pair** of keys. That is not just a syntactic difference.

Comment: @SkryptX Thanks dude, perfect answer

Comment: @dnoeth ok, yes. I was impatient. I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this syntax is not correct:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    a INT PRIMARY KEY,
    b INT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

A primary key is *primary* because only one can be defined.  Presumably, you intend a composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    a INT,
    b INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
);
```

The foreign key relationships are entirely different.  The second creates *two* foreign key relationships.  With a composite primary key, it would fail, because the reference should be to a primary key (or at least a unique key).

Comment: Yeah, I messed up the question. I was interested whether there is difference between multi-column foreign key and multiple foreign keys